# Transfer list with huge number of items, is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, item, data

I have list that contains 3 516 305 items (over 3 million). What would be the best approach to transferring whole list with all 3 million items?

Can I use ShareGate to transfer all items without issue, if yes is there something that I need to be cautious about? Do I just select everything at once and let it copy?

If it's possible with Sharegate, do you have idea of how long it would take?